# run created gem as sudo

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am working on a gem and am trying to write to the `/etc/hosts` file however permission is denied as a normal user. Trying to do it via `sudo appname patch_hostfile` results in the following

```
.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:284:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem appname (>= 0.a) with executable vcdm (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
```

I think it is doing this because `rake install` only installs for the current user but `sudo` should have access to everything so I'm not sure if that is the problem.

Comment: Does root have that gem installed? In 99% of cases when a computer tells you it cannot find something, the reason is that the something isn't there. (Computers are very good at finding things, they don't just "overlook" something.) In 99% of the rest of the cases, the reason is that the place you are telling the computer to look is not what you think it is. It looks like you are using RVM. Does root have RVM installed? Does root have RVM loaded? Is it also loaded in the sudo environment?

Comment: Try `sudo -s` and then in the shell it spawns run `appname patch_hostfile`.

Comment: @anothermh that didn't work..

Comment: @JörgWMittag how do I check this? I think this might be the problem but I am not sure how to check this.